# How to check if p:dialog is open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, primefaces

I have implemented a pop up box on my webpage using

```
<p:dialog header="Value" widgetVar="confirmationCbxTxt" ..>
```

Now, I want to check  whether this pop up box is open when clicking on a Button on my page.
The code for my Button is

```
<p:commandButton value="#{label.close}" ajax="true" id="Close2" onclick="focuspopup();" />
```

Using the onclick function "onclick="focuspopup();" I want to check whether my pop up box is open on the screen. Could any one suggest the approach . I am thinking of using jquery inside my focuspopup() to test for open popup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Client side API for `PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog` contains three methods, according to the [PrimeFaces 5.2 User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_2.pdf) (page 184):

- **show()** Displays dialog.
- **hide()** Closes dialog.
- **isVisible()** Returns visibility as a boolean.

Use the last one to satisfy the requirements. For instance, add this in your `focuspopup()` function:

```
var open = PF('confirmationCbxTxt').isVisible();
```

---

**Notes:** For older PrimeFaces versions (5.1 and below), **isVisible()** does not exist so you need to replace it by

```
var open = PF('confirmationCbxTxt').jq.is(':visible');
```

Comment: Hi Mathieu , the format PF(   doesn't work for me. Can u suggest any other format

Comment: Yes, `confirmationCbxTxt.isVisible();` if using an old pf version. This can also be read all over the internet. If you use PF, keep up with the blogs, scan the forum from time to time, **use the documentation** etc

Comment: Which PrimeFaces version are you using? Also, as it should work as described above, please report any JS errors from your browser debugger console

Comment: Wow! Why are you stuck with this old version (2011!), if you can, you should upgrade. Anyway, `isVisible()` wasn't part of the client side API in PrimeFaces 2.2. You should play around with jQuery.

Comment: What about `var open = confirmationCbxTxt.jq.hasClass('ui-overlay-visible');`? It that works for you, I will update my answer.

Comment: No. You should only need a widgetVar such as `widgetVar="confirmationCbxTxt"`

Comment: You should tell us what says your console. You might have some JS errors that could help to narrow down the problem.

Comment: there are no errors. the problem is that, with" var open = confirmationCbxTxt.jq.hasClass('ui-overlay-visible');" value of open is always false. even when there is no pop up

Comment: I don't get it, sorry. When there is no pop up, it's usual to get open = false.

Comment: but with pop up also , open=false

Comment: `var open = confirmationCbxTxt.jq.is(':visible');`? Sorry, I run out of ideas, I cannot set up a PF 2.2 environment right now.